# Which language is best to handle extremely large numbers?

Tags: windows, numbers, integer, bigdata

I want to handle extremely large integer values of a few million digits for an experiment I'm conducting.
Which language is best for this? I know some languages such as batch have pre-established limits on how many digits it can handle.

I have a large RAM and 64-bit OS, so my machine isn't a problem.

Regards,

-Master-chip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in python 3.x the int type does not have a limit so if you are just looking for a suggestion I would check out python.

see https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers

What are you looking to do with the numbers?  If your number is larger than the maximum value of an unsigned 64 bit long is 18446744073709551615 then you won't be able to use the normal types and will want to look at languages that support bigInts http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Honestly there are solutions for this in most languages you will just have to pick the one you want to work with and look at its solution

- Can you store these values as Strings?
- Do you need complete accuracy of the numbers or can you store them as floats

Comment: I need my numbers to be as accurate as possible. I guess I can store them as strings though. Are there any other languages? What do you mean by 'not a normal typed language'?

Comment: typed languages are where you declare the type of each variable the main ones are java, c++, c#

Comment: if you're not running math operations on the numbers but instead storing them for reporting reasons then I would recommend using Strings

Comment: It's a program that works fairly big prime numbers for a work project. I've got the basic equation sorted and a rough sketch of what to write done. Which non-typed language do you suggest? Is it still Python?

Comment: Yep I would try to do this with Python.  Once you have the code written if anything goes wrong just write a new post and it will be easier for the  community to help once there is a code example